# respond_to do |format| gives "UnknownFormat in UsersController#show" in rails 5 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, respond-to

In my rails 5 app I want to render partials in a `div` in the `views/users/show.html.erb` on link click.

I believe I have set things up accordingly but rails gives me this error `ActionController::UnknownFormat in UsersController#show`

`ActionController::UnknownFormat`

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :show_kwst }
end
```

I'm kind of lost here, I've done similar things in rail 4 by using `bootstrap tabs` with out any problems.

I've also added the `'responders' gem` to the `gemfile`

This is my `views/users/show.html.erb`

```
<%= link_to 'Kwst', user_path%>

<div id="content"></div>
```

This is my `users_controller.rb`

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    @user_posts = @user.posts
    @user_kwsts = @user.kwsts


    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :show_kwst }
    end

  end

end
```

And here is the `views/users/show_kwst.js.erb``

```
$("#content").html("<%=escape_javascript(render :partial=>"shared/show_kwst")%>");
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try `format.js { render 'show_kwst.js.erb' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to the following order, you can follow this [`Rails Guide About format.js`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example)

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html { @user_kwsts }
   format.js
end
```

Notice the [`format.js`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example) in the `respond_to` block; that allows the controller to respond to your Ajax request. You then have a corresponding `app/views/users/show_kwst.js.erb` view file that generates the actual JavaScript code that will be sent and executed on the client side.

Comment: This makes the error goes away, but the link is not working.  As in it seems to be dead :) I added `:remote => true` to the end of the link but without any luck.

Comment: this works perfectly, I had a typo in the partialname, thats why the link didn´t respont :) Thank you for the solution